# Bluemix Single Sign for Node.js throws 'crypto.createCredentials is deprecated' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I'm stuck in an attempt to configure the Bluemix Single Sign On service in my Node.js app.

Both Cloud Directory and Google+ API identity providers keep failing with the following error message:

```
(node) crypto.createCredentials is deprecated. Use tls.createSecureContext instead.
  at /home/vcap/app/node_modules/passport-idaas-openidconnect/node_modules/oauth/lib/
  oauth2.js:160:18
  at ...
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
```

The best answer for this I could find is below, but what I think is that the suggested code lines should be within the passport-idaas-openidconnect package. Is that idea correct?

```
if (tls.createSecureContext) {
  credentials = tls.createSecureContext(config.options.cryptoCredentialsDetails);
} else {
  credentials = crypto.createCredentials(@config.options.cryptoCredentialsDetails);
}
```

The app uses the following npm package versions:

```
   ├── body-parser@1.15.0
   ├── cookie-parser@1.4.1
   ├── express@4.13.4
   ├── express-session@1.13.0
   ├── passport@0.3.2
   └── passport-idaas-openidconnect@1.0.0 extraneous
```

It also uses this Node.js version:

```
-----> IBM SDK for Node.js Buildpack v3.0-20160125-1224
   Based on Cloud Foundry Node.js Buildpack v1.5.4
```

Answer (score 0):

The passport-idaas-openidconnect at the moment is using an old version of the OAuth module (version 0.9.10). The depreciated issue appears to have been resolved in versions 0.9.13 and higher, where the latest at the moment is 0.9.14.

See: https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth/commit/de3a067aba4a045c5c7320928e5e146077ea5310

Until the passport-idaas-openidconnect module gets updated to use a later OAuth module, you can try to manually change the passport-idaas-openeidconnect's package.json file to use an OAuth module version with the fix and then include your now customized passport-idaas-openidconnect module by removing it from the ignore file and the package.json in your app directory when pushing your app to Bluemix.